# EM Field Interacting with Two Level System (With Permanent Dipoles)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-optics, two-level-system

I have started from Schrodinger equation:
$${i\hbar\frac{\partial}{{\partial}t}}|Ψ(t)\rangle=H(t)|Ψ(t)\rangle$$
With Hamiltonian of this kind:
$$H(t)=H_0+V_{int}$$
With eigenstates $$H_0|n\rangle=\hbarω_n|n\rangle$$ where $$i=1,2$$I supposed that for the whole Hamiltonian a solution exists and is of this kind:
$$|Ψ(t)\rangle=a_1(t)|1\rangle  e^{-iω_1t}+a_2(t)|2\rangle e^{-iω_2t}$$
By replacing and after all the necessary steps I end up with these two differential equations.

[image: Equations for amplitudes]

Where

[image]

By using RWA and dipole moments and our external field is resonant to the energy difference we end up with these equations

[image]

When μ11 and μ22 are zero the solution is simple, but in this problem they are not zero. I defined new variables:

[image]

So the equations became:

[image]

From now on I have to somehow use this:

[image]

To find solutions for b1 and b2 but I don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: One could first get rid of the terms containing $\mu_{11}, \mu_{22}$ and only then do the rotating wave approximation for the Harmonic of interest, satisfying teh resonance condition $\omega_2 - \omega_1 = \pm \omega$.

Comment: I know the solution with getting rid of the terms μ11, μ22 and it was my previous exercise. But in this one we have to consider that the two level system corresponds to a molecule with permanent dipole moment so we can't get rid of these terms and must calculate a solution for b1, b2 depending on μ21, μ11, μ22.

Comment: What I mean is exchange the steps in your derivation: first introduce $b_{1,2}(t)$ and only then do the RWA for the specific harmonic.

Comment: I added as an answer the way I think about it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before performing the RWA one has:
$$i\dot{a}_1 = (\omega_1 - v_{11}\cos\omega t)a_1(t) - v_{12}a_2\cos\omega t,\\
i\dot{a}_2 = - v_{21}a_1\cos\omega t +
(\omega_2 - v_{22}\cos\omega t)a_2(t),$$
where for brevity I have introduced notation $v_{ij} = \langle i|\frac{\vec{\mu}\hat{\epsilon}E_0}{\hbar}|j\rangle$.
We can now introduce new variables as
$$a_1(t) = b_1(t)e^{-i\omega_1 t + i\frac{v_{11}}{\omega}\sin\omega t},\\
a_2(t) = b_2(t)e^{-i\omega_2 t + i\frac{v_{22}}{\omega}\sin\omega t}.
$$
In terms of these variables the Schrödinger equation takes form
$$i\dot{b}_1(t) = -v_{12}b_2(t)e^{-i(\omega_2 - \omega_1)t + i\frac{v_{22}-v_{11}}{\omega}\sin\omega t}\cos(\omega t),\\
i\dot{b}_2(t) = -v_{21}b_1(t)e^{i(\omega_2 - \omega_1)t - i\frac{v_{22}-v_{11}}{\omega}\sin\omega t}\cos(\omega t).$$
We can now write
$$e^{-i(\omega_2 - \omega_1)t + i\frac{v_{22}-v_{11}}{\omega}\sin\omega t}\cos(\omega t)=
\frac{1}{2}e^{-i(\omega_2 - \omega_1)t}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}J_n\left(\frac{v_{22}-v_{11}}{\omega}\right)e^{in\omega t}\left(e^{-i\omega t} + e^{i\omega t}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}J_n\left(\frac{v_{22}-v_{11}}{\omega}\right)\left(e^{-i[\omega_2 - \omega_1 -(n-1)\omega] t} + e^{-i[\omega_2 - \omega_1 -(n+1)\omega] t}\right).$$
If frequency $\omega$ is bigger than the level broadening, we can limit ourselves to the combination of frequencies closest to the resonance and perform random wave approximation. Let the detuning be $\delta = \omega_2 - \omega_1 -m\omega$, then from the first sum we keep only the term with $n=m+1$ (i.e. $n-1 = m$), whereas from the second sum the term with $n=m-1$:
$$i\dot{b}_1(t) = -\frac{v_{12}}{2}b_2(t)\left[J_{m+1}\left(\frac{v_{22}-v_{11}}{\omega}\right) + J_{m-1}\left(\frac{v_{22}-v_{11}}{\omega}\right)\right]e^{-i\delta t},\\
i\dot{b}_2(t) = -\frac{v_{21}}{2}b_1(t)\left[J_{m+1}\left(\frac{v_{11}-v_{22}}{\omega}\right) + J_{m-1}\left(\frac{v_{11}-v_{22}}{\omega}\right)\right]e^{i\delta t}.$$
These are the same equations that we get for the case without permanent dipole moment, but with redefined matrix elements.